# Regex IBM DB2 iSeries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Can anyone give me a clue, how to create/call function regular expression syntax in DB2 iSeries.

Example:

```
DECLARE VAL VARCHAR (16) DEFAULT 'abcde1235876e' ;
DECLARE RET INT DEFAULT 0;
```

I'm just checking VARIABLE VAL must only contain numeric value and return true/false

```
SET VAL = I_NEED_FUNCTION_REGEX(VAL);
IF (VAL = true) THEN
SET RET = 1;
ELSE
SET RET = 0;
END IF;
```

as simple as that, but i've been searching in IBM as follows:

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

but i don't quite understand.

Can u help me ?

---

### UPDATE

I'm back to the old way and simple for now.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST.VALIDATE_NUMERIC (VAL CHARACTER VARYING(1))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC TEST.VALIDATE_NUMERIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
FENCED
DISALLOW PARALLEL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE RET INT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION , SQLWARNING , NOT FOUND

IF ( VAL IS NOT NULL ) THEN

CASE VAL
WHEN 0 THEN -- (0)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 1 THEN -- (1)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 2 THEN -- (2)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 3 THEN -- (3)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 4 THEN -- (4)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 5 THEN -- (5)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 6 THEN -- (6)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 7 THEN -- (7)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 8 THEN -- (8)
SET RET = 1 ;
WHEN 9 THEN -- (9)
SET RET = 1 ;
ELSE
SET RET = 0 ;
END CASE ;

END IF ;

RETURN RET ;  
END 
GO
```

Thanks
MRizq

Comment: Is there somethign wrong with the condition `CASE WHEN VAL >= 0 AND VAL <= 9`?  Much quicker and easer to understand, and less likely to have a digit dropped during updating.  Oh, and the standard on the iSeries for 'truth' values is a _character_ `1`, not a _numeric_ value (because that's what indicators are using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, DB2 does *not* come with the capability to handle regex.  There are *some* functions to handle some pattern matching, but it's severly restricted.

The article you linked is how to set up a UDF (user-defined function) to call out to an external (C) library to provide this functionality.  While the steps are shown for LUW, the iSeries version should be roughly equivalent; you're going to have to talk your DBAs into implementing the call out to relevant libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LOCATE(VAL, '0123456789')` to return a 0 if not numeric and the digit + 1 if found:

```
CASE LOCATE(VAL, '0123456789') WHEN > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

For a multi-character string you can use the following:

```
CASE WHEN TRANSLATE(TRIM(VAL), '0', '0123456789', '0') 
    = REPEAT('0', LENGTH(TRIM(VAL))) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```